# Removing clear coat from a soft top.

Tags: paint-clearcoat, soft-top

Is it possible to remove overspray clear coat from a soft top? Some areas are very faint and 'light' and some areas are embedded. Should I use a solvent? There really isn't much info in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Use "rubbing alcohol," aka isopropyl alcohol. Get it from the drugstore or the pharmacy.